# How to set babel on create-react-app Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, axios, create-react-app

I'm doing React.js project that created by create-react-app. I use axios to connect with server, so I have to use babel-polyfill to support IE11. create-react-app doesn't have webpack.config.js file to modify 'entry', so I can't set babel.

Also I tried to insert `import 'babel-polyfill';` and `require('babel-polyfill');` on javascript file that using axios. But it didn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: download babel-polufill and then use var babel=require('downloaded location')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create-react-app includes only a few polyfills to reduce the code size (ES6 polyfills are large).

If you want to add `babel-polyfill` without modifying webpack configs, you need to import it at the entry-point to your application, before anything else is called

```
// on top of your index.js
import 'babel-polyfill'
```